# Parse Push Notification working on Emulator but not working on Android device

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, device

I have created an chat application in android. It is working fine . Also notifications are working on emulators. But when I try it on device there seems no notification receiving. I followed tutorials of parse regarding Android for message and notification but still on device there is no notification coming. Guide me regarding the same.

*My manifest file has following permissions:*

```
package="com.gestureMsg.messenger"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
            android:name="com.gestureMsg.messenger.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.gestureMsg.messenger.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name="packgest.MessengerApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/msg"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
       android:value="id:1076345567071" />;

    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/msg"/>

     <activity android:name="packgest.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity android:name="packgest.CurrentUserActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
     <activity android:name="packgest.NewUserActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
     <activity android:name="packgest.ShowContactsWithApp" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
     <activity android:name="packgest.ViewProfileActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
     <activity android:name="packgest.RefreshActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
     <activity android:name="packgest.AfterNotificationActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

     <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

     <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
      </intent-filter>
     </receiver>

 <!--   <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false"> -->
    <receiver android:name="packgest.Reciever" android:exported="false"> 
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
              android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <category android:name="com.gestureMsg.messenger" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

*My push code is :*

```
// Notification for Android users
       ParsePush androidPush = new ParsePush();
       androidPush.setMessage(currentUser.getUsername());
       androidPush.setQuery(query);
       androidPush.sendInBackground();`
```

*My application class code :*

```
public class MessengerApplication extends Application {

private final static String APP_ID="xxx";
private final static String CLIENT_KEY ="xxx";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());

    Parse.initialize(getApplicationContext(),APP_ID,CLIENT_KEY);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();



    //  the channel "" is called the "broadcast" channel and is used for broadly applicable messages
    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() 
    {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e)
        {
            if (e == null)
            {
                Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                System.out.println("successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            } 
            else 
            {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
                System.out.println("failed to subscribe for push."+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, CurrentUserActivity.class);

    super.onCreate();
}
}
```

Comment: Is your device connected to Internet? Can you show the code where you initialize Parse?

Comment: yes my device is connected to internet. I added the code of Application class where parse is initialised

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046706/parse-push-notification-just-work-in-emulator

Comment: I have made changes according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046706/parse-push-notification-just-work-in-emulator but still there is no effect.