# push notifications using parse.com not recieved on device

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, device

This is my code to send a push notification using parse.com in android.

```html
ParseQuery installQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
     installQuery.whereEqualTo("userId",  recieverObjectID);
     



ParsePush androidPush = new ParsePush();
         androidPush.setMessage(currentUser.getUsername());
         androidPush.setQuery(installQuery);
         androidPush.sendInBackground();
```

In emulator I am able to send and receive push notifications, but I am not able to receive push notification on device. I manage to retrieve that in Installation table of parse when push-type is gcm for those devices or emulators push notifications are not sent. Guide me with solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse Push Notification just work in Emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046706/parse-push-notification-just-work-in-emulator)

Comment: I referred the link and worked accordingly still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you are having a Parse account please go through the docs provided over there that will help you alot. you will have to make a class of parse application
public class ParseApplication  extends Application{



   public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

          Parse.initialize(this,"app_id","Client_id");



        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();




        }
```

}

```
 then in your launcher activity you have to intialise parse like this:

 ParseInstallation currentInstall=ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
```

Comment: I have read all docs of parse.com but still no results. I am not getting why push are not recieved by devices.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made Parse Installation table as given in the docs.? you will have to register your device on Parse.

Answer (score 0):

firstly do this:
          ParsePush androidPush = new ParsePush();
                        androidPush.setMessage(currentUser.getUsername());
                        androidPush.setQuery(installQuery);
                        androidPush.saveInBackground();
check your manifest then u are Missing with some permissions can be Internet Permission or given below:
               
           
        
         
         then in the application tag:

```
   <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
   <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
     <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
      <category android:name="YOUR PACKAGE NAME" />
   </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
      <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"           android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
     <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
     </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
```

Answer (score -2):

OK. So then in Your parse Account go and click on Push You will surely get a push.